# Looking Ahead: What does the faculty job market for 2022 look like in *your* field?

Tags: job-search, tenure-track, covid-19

The job market for Fall, 2022 tenure-track faculty positions can start as early as now (July, 2021) for many fields. To date, I haven't seen many articles on what the the 2021-2022 job market season will look like in the continuing wake of the pandemic. Although it's early, **what do Fall, 2022 faculty openings look like for your discipline?** How does that compare to the past? Will there be more positions, fewer positions, different kinds of positions (eg. Adjunct, Teaching)? Hoping to help everyone gain a little more "situational awareness" in these still-uncertain times.

Comment: I can certainly understand everyone's interest in a substantive answer to such a question, but I'd have no hope of a sensible answer... At my R1 U.S. univ it's still all completely ambiguous... all the more so give the resurgence of ambiguity about the variant Covid strain... Any sane answer here would be negative... and completely imprecise, I think.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that's an answer in and of itself, isn't it? "We don't know yet/it's uncertain" is more information than I had when I posted the question! So thank you!